# DHCP Admin Member account not displaying scope

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

I made a domain name test.com on serv1 computer with dc and dns roles.  On serv2 pc i added it to the domain and added the role of dhcp with 1 scope and authorized it and it is working fine.

I created a new user name dhcppavan@test.com and added it to the DHCP Administrators Group (proof: http://clip2net.com/s/1rQm8), I am able to log in into serv2 with this account but when I open the dhcp console I am not able to see the scope and other options.  Here is the image of dhcp when when i log in as dhcppavan@test.com account "http://clip2net.com/s/1rQja".

It is a fresh setup on both pc hence not many changes are made, all of them are default.

Could you please tell me where I have gone wrong on this test bed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User must be enrolled as member of DHCP admin group on that local machine too where DHCP role is to be administered.